# Многочисленные try-catch

Tags: java, javascript

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли (и если да, то как) заменить несколько блоков try-catch на один, но с таким же функционалом (с сохранением замены значения на -1)?

```
try
{
    temp.year = Integer.parseInt(year.getText());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    temp.year = -1;
}
try
{
    temp.v = Integer.parseInt(v.getText());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    temp.v = -1;
}
try
{
    temp.maxSpeed = Integer.parseInt(maxSpeed.getText());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    temp.maxSpeed = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Просто создайте метод `parseIntSafe` и передавайте в него значения:

```
public static int parseIntSafe(String value) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Стоит еще предусмотреть обработку `null`.

Comment: +1, хотя переход от исключений к значениям, представляющим ошибку, — явный шаг назад. (Впрочем, претензии не к вам, а к автору вопроса, который хочет писать на Java, как на C.)

Comment: У меня не значение, представляющее ошибку, просто хочу, чтобы при неверных входных данных было хоть какое-нибудь значение и не выбивало исключения. Я только учусь, поэтому пишу, как умею.

Comment: @melodicwing: подумайте над вопросом — а _как_ окружающий код узнает, что произошла ошибка? В чём проблема с исключением — не нужно ли просто его словить там, где надо?

Answer (score 0):

try multicatch{Exception e, e1, e2} (Только с java 7)

Comment: А как определить, какого именно поля значение нужно заменять на -1?

Comment: Хм, на null ввести проверки.
_____
Будет как-то так:

    try
    {
    temp.year = Integer.parseInt(year.getText());
    temp.v = Integer.parseInt(v.getText());
    temp.maxSpeed = Integer.parseInt(maxSpeed.getText());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    if (temp.v == null)
    temp.v = -1;
    }

Можно в принципе тернарнами операторами записать все 3 if-а.

Comment: Спасибо.  
И еще один вопрос, в таком случае, чтобы не создавать отдельную тему.
Если у меня есть такой класс:  
`public class CAuto {String mark; int year; int v; int maxSpeed; public CAuto(){} }`  
То чему будут равны поля year, v и maxSpeed после создания экземпляра такого класса?

Comment: Объекты null, примитивы 0.